# How to automate dropdown box in selenium by xpath when id element is not available

Tags: java, selenium

Following is the html code :

Multiplier $ Value
Event $ Value

How can I select the event $ value from dropdown
Value by default selected is Multiplier $ Value. How do I change it to Event $

Comment: Your given HTML Code not like HTML code,  Please give the corrent HTML code

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with js

```
var fld = document.getElementById('your_id');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fld.options.length; i++) {
  if (fld.options[i].selected) {
    values.push(fld.options[i].value);
  }
}
```